# 'net view' generates error "The service has not been started"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, service, windows-service

I have a problem in Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager where by the computer browser to do a remote push install has randomly stopped working showing the error message

```
Network Provider: Microsoft Windows Network Error: The service has not been started
```

so I searched around online and also tested `net view` in Command Prompt which shows the error message

```
C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN>net view
The service has not been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2184.
```

I have checked both `Computer Browser` and `Workstation` services and both were running but I also restarted them and I have the same error messages. Does anyone know how I can resolve the issue?

Comment: Old thread, but does `NET VIEW \\COMPUTERNAME` work properly?

Comment: For me yes! Only NET VIEW does not... but then again, my own computer does not show up on explorer network view...

Answer (score 0):

`Computer Browser` also depends on the **`Server`** service. Have you checked that it's running?